# If i have newer ruby and clone older ruby project will i break project upon merge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I can't seem to find this simple yes no question online so sorry for the super noob question!

I'm using an EC2 instance for my development and I set it up to have ruby 2.1.1 and rails 4.1. I have RVM, but don't actually have any other ruby versions.

I cloned my friends project and told him I would start helping him. His project is a ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0.4.

He's concerned that when I merge changes it will update the project to 2.1.1 and rails 4.1 and then it will crash on his computer (since he doesn't have 2.1.1 or rails 4.1)

I don't think this is the case, but I'm not 100% sure, so how valid are his concerns? I was under the assumption that as long as I don't use any functionality from rails 4.1 and 2.1.1 that isn't in 4.0.4 or 2.0.0 then there is no need to be concerned. Also, I assume when I cloned the project and make changes to it, it should stay in 4.0.4 and 2.0.0 versions. Is that true?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: You should take a look at the upgrade [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html), it's very easy to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails version should be defined in Gemfile, so unless you change it, it will stay the same (and when you run `bundle install` the proper version will be installed if it's missing, so even on your computer you will not work on Rails 4.1, but on Rails 4.0.4).

With Ruby version it's a bit more complicated, because it can be defined in some file (like .rvmrc or .ruby-version), but does not have to. Still, if you don't change anything in project's configuration, neither Ruby nor Rails version will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are physically merging a 4.1 into the 4.0.4, then you will most likely encounter some issues. (I don't know the exact differences between those versions, but a full minor version up usually comes with new/changed goodies)

If you are just working on each app separately, then they would be isolated by their Gemfile. This is assuming the Gemfile.lock has been saved into the repo. Or the versions have been locked in the Gemfile itself.

Your Ruby version probably won't matter if you are running the `bundle install` fresh on your current version. Unless there are specific needs for a specific version.